# How to install barcodescanner-plugin on Cordova/Phonegap - Eclipse for Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, barcode-scanner

Can I get help to install http://phonegap.com/blog/build/barcodescanner-plugin/ on Phonegap? I'm using ADK eclipse to use build an Android app. I would appreciate if somebody could explain the plugin installation process step-by-step. From downloading from git and installing the plugin.

Comment: What version of phonegap are you using?

Answer (score 9):

With 3.1, here is what works for me:

Create your project

```
cordova create example com.example Example
```

Change to your project directory and then add Android

```
cd example
cordova platform add android
```

Get the plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git
```

Build the project

```
cordova build android
```

After that everything appeared to be in the right place.

Comment: One thing I hate about phonegap is its pesky docs! You made my day! Thank

Answer (score 1):

I installed the plugin via plugman:

```
sudo npm install -g plugman
plugman install --platform android --project myproject/platforms/android/ --plugin https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner.git
```